# How to change the audio routing at system level in iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio

Is it possible to change the audio route when headphones are plug in or unplugged at iPhone's system level. Actually i want to listen the input and output audio only from internal iphone microphones whether headphones is connected or not.I have tried with kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker , it is working fine at application level but not at system level. It is an enterprise applications. Any idea? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Audio session programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audio/conceptual/audiosessionprogrammingguide/introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/tp40007875) guide from Apple. You can only force play a audio file through iPhone speakers from app level by using setting `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` to `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker`. AFAIK system level it is not possible